# Calculating the area of selected parts in an aerial image

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to calculate the area of vegetation in aerial image but I don't have the information regarding the height at which the image is taken. By using the RGB values, I've extracted the vegetation area in the image. The area that does not hold vegetation has been set to black (eg; (0,0,0)).

How do I proceed from this step?

Comment: Without some kind of scaling reference, you can't. Ideally, you'd want there to be something of a known size in the image so that you can work out the dimensions of the area of interest based off that. Failing that, some knowledge of the camera optics and the aircraft's position/orientation would also suffice, but you've indicated that isn't an option. In short, your only option is to guess.

Comment: how will i go about guessing some reference

Comment: I don't quite see how there is a reliable / robust method to estimate sizes. I know from some assignments that I made that (in case of moon craters) they use a single crater as a reference size and calculate all others based on that. This would mean that if your initial estimate(s) are off, so will all your results be off.

Comment: do you not know the size of the area the camera is looking at? If you can work that out then just count pixels and relate to SI units

Comment: @Sharan: as GPPK mentions, if you know how big the image is you can then figure out how big your area is. Other than that, if there's some other object in the image that you can estimate the size of (a tree, building, road, etc), then you can estimate the scale of the image and then estimate the area of your vegetated area.